# Ошибка валидации rss страницы

Tags: rss

Вообще не понимаю за rss страницы. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть быть решение проблемы. В гугле ничего похожего не нашел((

https://www.btb.su/blog/rss/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложите текстом ссылку rss

Comment: Ссылка ведет на ваш сайт?

Comment: @gil9red https://www.btb.su/blog/rss/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас стоит вначале закрывающий тег `description`, но нет открывающегося.

1. Откройте файл rss в режиме правки, найдите 6-ю строку вот
   эту(`<description/>`)
2. Добавьте перед ним `<description>Блог BTB` То-бишь строка должна
   выглядеть вот так `<description>Блог BTB</description>` Это нужно
   сделать со всеми такими тегами в RSS. У вас таких блоков несколько. Для каждой ссылки свое описание.
3. Сохраните и закройте файл.